# array, the difference between VS2010 and Mingw

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mingw

in the с++ Primer 5th edition I read that for array assigment operator is not allowed. I tried compile this (on MinGw 5.1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    array<int, 10> arr = {1,2,3};
    arr = {}; //1

    return 0;
}
```

and it's all ok, all working fine. But when i tried compile this on MS VS2010 it's got me the error on 1. who is right VS2010 or MinGW.

Comment: MinGW is providing an advance way of doing it, which is not supported by the older version of C++ compilers such as VS2010.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx (initializer list)

Comment: Update to VS2017 (community edition is free).

Comment: This is a C++11 feature, it reminds you that 2010 < 2011.

Comment: so it turns out in Primer 5th is the error?